# How to interpret standardized coefficients for an interaction effect between continuous and categorical variables?

Tags: least-squares, interaction, standardization

It is conventional, in some circles, to standardize all continuous variables before conducting OLS regression. It is argued that this actions makes it possible to rank the effects observed, and hence know which variables better explain the dependent variable than others. My question is: "How do I rank standardized coefficients when an interaction term includes a continuous variable and a categorical variable?"

Consider the following MWE using the `diamonds` dataset from the `tidyverse` package in `R`. I've simplified this example by dichotomizing the responses for color into G and not G, represented using the numbers `1` and `0`, respectively.

```r
library("tidyverse")
data("diamonds")

diamonds <- diamonds %>%
    mutate(color = if_else(color == "G", 1, 0))

results <- lm(I(scale(price)) ~ I(scale(carat))*color + I(scale(table)), data = diamonds)
summary(results)
```

The results are as follows:
[image]

The table shows an interaction effect between `carat` and `color`. The unique effect of `carat` on `price` for color G is `0.909950`. Additionally, the unique effect of `carat` on `price` for all colors not equal to G is `0.909950+0.109585=1.019535`.

Do I then interpret these effects like I would in a standardized main effects only model? Is the effect of `carat` on `price` for diamonds of color G less than the effect of `carat` on `price` for diamonds of some other color? Can I also compare these effects to main effects? Is the effect of `carat` on `price` for diamonds whose colors differ from G greater, in magnitude, than the effect of `table`?

Comment: I think the algorithm choice in this case, `linear regression` is an incorrect choice for determining the interaction affect between categorical and continuous variables. Try logistic regression.